# Python: ImportError: No module named os

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django, mod-wsgi

**error_log**

```
...
[Fri Sep 07 16:30:14 2012] [error] import os
[Fri Sep 07 16:30:14 2012] [error] ImportError: No module named os
```

**-shell-**

```
[root@lts5srv1 home]# ldd /root/epd-5.1.0/bin/python
    libpython2.5.so.1.0 => /root/epd-5.1.0/lib/libpython2.5.so.1.0 (0x00002b0829205000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003da0600000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003d9fe00000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000003dadc00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003da0200000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003d9fa00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d9f600000)
```

Anybody know how to solve this error? it's the only error that i get when i try to run a python script or a django.wsgi script in a redhat system, after that i'm going to upload my web-app in a university server... and i've already configuret the VirtualHost. So that was the only problem, can anybody help please? Thank You.

Comment: Which path did you set `WSGIPythonPath` to?

Comment: /root/epd-5.1.0/bin/python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me, was: re-installing a new version of Python and the other needed modules inside the new Python site-packages folder. Follow this link to see the various steps..:
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320143/python-importerror-no-module-named-os)

Answer (score 0):

[`WSGIPythonPath`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath) is used to search for Python modules, not the path to Python binary. Point it to something like `/usr/lib/python2.7/` and try again.

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/python2.7/os.py*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26300 Mar  7  2012 /usr/lib/python2.7/os.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26035 Mar  7  2012 /usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26035 Mar  7  2012 /usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyo
```

Comment: i've changed to this: /root/epd-5.1.0/lib/python2.5

Comment: and doesn't work! It still generates the same error.

Comment: Does `os` module exist in `/root/epd-5.1.0/lib/python2.5`? How many Python versions on your system?

Comment: yes, it exists.

Comment: it is missing only "os.pyo"..

Comment: my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320143/python-importerror-no-module-named-os