# No Module Named OS - NGINX/UWSGI/NGINX

Tags: nginx, python, django, uwsgi

Have looked at many related posts and most point to an outdated version of python that is cause the 'no module named os' during the uwsgi boot. I've run

```
print sys.version_info
```

And it shows python 2.7, which all the other sources say is recent enough.

My .ini file looks like:

```
[uwsgi]

chdir = app/app/
module = wsgi.py:application
no-site = true
virtualenv  = app_venv

master = true
processes = 10

socket = app.sock
chmod-socket = 777
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

And when I run:

```
  uwsgi --ini app.ini
```

I see:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
  import os
 ImportError: No module named os
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: I figured it was just a missing module but: http://serverfault.com/questions/425365/python-importerror-no-module-named-os . Apparently it should be install w/ python.